# Will karaf work in java 6?

Tags: apache-karaf, java-6, osgi-bundle, karaf

Will Karaf work in Java 6?
Which version of Apache karaf does support Java 6 (jdk 1.6.21).

I wanted to deploy my OSGI bundles in Karaf. Anyone who is aware of this information, please let me know.

Apache karaf installation documents doesn't clear my doubt. The latest karaf version(3.x or 4.x) document says it supports JAVA SE 7/8 and the lower version(2.4.x) says it supports Java SE 5.

Please clarify my doubt. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is now working fine with the Apache karaf version 2.3.10.

Answer (score 1):

The Karaf 2.x line supports Java 6.
Karaf 3 only supports Java 7 and higher
Karaf 4.1 will depend on Java 8 as minimum version.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the version support directly at the official karaf website : http://karaf.apache.org/download.html.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I have already referred this link.
I have also tried using 3.0.6 version of karaf as given here. But my karaf is started with exception when starting the karaf.bat file from command prompt. Below is the exception: